# Merging with different modules

Tags: ruby, classes, inheritance, modules

We have an action merge for two projects. In the projects we have different modules like Feed, Files, Post etc....

```
modules Convert
class Merge
    attr_accessor :source_ids, :destination_id, :sources, :destination

    def initialize(source_ids, destination_id)
        @source_ids = source_ids.class == Array ? source_ids : [source_ids]
        @destination_id = destination_id
        @sources = Modelname.where("id in (?)", @source_ids).all
        @destination = Modelname.where("id in (?)", @destination_id).first
    end

    def merge
        sources.each do |source|
          ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            Convert::Feed.new(source, destination).merge
            Convert::File.new(source, destination).merge
            Convert::Post.new(source, destination).merge
            ## There are many more modules - code comes here
          end
        end
    end
end

class Feed
    def initialize(source, destination)
        @source = source
        @destination = destination
    end

    def merge
        #Feed merge code here
    end

end

class File
    def initialize(source, destination)
        @source = source
        @destination = destination
    end

    def merge
        #File merge code here
    end

end

class Post
    def initialize(source, destination)
        @source = source
        @destination = destination
    end

    def merge
        #Post merge code here
    end

end
end


a = Convert::Merge.new(source_id, destionation_id)
a.merge
```

Is this correct way to handle this action ? How can I handle this in a better way ?

Comment: krunal, you could write `@source_ids = source_ids.class == Array ? source_ids : [source_ids]` as `@source_ids = [*source_ids]`.  For example, `[*[1,2,3]] => [1, 2, 3]`, `[*2] => [2]`.

Comment: My question is not about only passing an parameters. Question is about pattern I used is correct or not ?

Comment: krunal, I should have said I was just making a small point, not addressing your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is nowhere near the full answer, but I just want to touch on the initialize method of Merge real quick since it was the first thing to jump out to me.

```
def initialize(destination_id, *source_ids)
  @source_ids = source_ids
  @destination_id = destination_id
  @sources = Modelname.where(id: @source_ids).all
  @destination = Modelname.where(id: @destination_id).first
end
```

This code is functionally equivalent. Using the splat operator at the end I guarantee the source ids will be in an array.  I'll keep looking at the rest of the code and go from there, but that was the first thing I wanted to point out.

Comment: @krunal_shah is the merge code the same for File, Feed, and Post?

Comment: No merge code for all the modules will be different.